# How to take a data file, read it, and having the output as a table in python

Tags: python

I am having a problem with a python coding problem where I must use one data file, write a program to read the file, in some way manipulate the data read, and produce an output report. The report must be a table with columns, I can not figure out how to create the columns. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not allowed to use outside packages, I have looked almost everywhere for code with out it. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: `output as a table` is too generic. Do you mean, just printed out on screen? Or printed on file? Stored in a table for further manipulation?

Comment: Also, include some code of what you've done, as it will help us better understand the context.

Comment: "in some way manipulate the data" how exactly? What manipulation should be done?

Comment: Apologies, I am a beginner programmer if you have not noticed. The table must be printed out into the screen. The "manipulation of data" is into a table. I will post code shortly.

Comment: To print text in columns, often times, each column in the same row is spaced using tabs `\t` or a certain amount of spaces. If you are able to loop through each row/column, a print statement like the following is a good starting point: `print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(col1, col2, col3, col4))`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to print the list

```
L = [['name', 'age', 'birth date'],
     ['john', '45', '29/01/1974'],
     ['steve', '17', '13/03/2002'],
     ['paul', '13', '22/05/2006']]
```

in table-format. The first step is to define the number of rows and columns in your table and save to variables, as this will help you up there.

### Print the table

Using a for loop, you can print all the informations like in a table.

```
for i in L:
    print(*i, sep='|', end='')
    print()
```

### Define the width of each column

After that, you can define a list `width` with the length values of each element per column.

That is, if you enter a list like

```
[['name', 'age', 'birth date'],
 ['john', '45', '29/01/1974'],
 ['steve', '17', '13/03/2002'],
 ['paul', '13', '22/05/2006']]
```

it should return `[5, 3, 10]`.

Note that in the first column the longest string is `'steve'` (**5** characters), the second column is `'age'` (**3** characters), and the third column all the strings have the same length (**10** characters).

### Define a vertical margin (optional)

Once you have created the table and printed it on the screen, you may encounter a problem like this:

```
name|age|birth date
john|45|29/01/1974
steve|17|13/03/2002
paul|13|22/05/2006
```

To solve this, you can apply to each string in the list a built-in method, such as `center`. The `width` list will help you in this, because it'll be possible to define the size of each argument of the method through each element of the list `width`.

### Define a horizontal line (optional)

For aesthetic reasons, you may want to separate the lines by a horizontal line, like this:

```
---------+-------+--------------
   name  |  age  |  birth date  
---------+-------+--------------
   john  |   45  |  29/01/1974  
---------+-------+--------------
  steve  |   17  |  13/03/2002  
---------+-------+--------------
   paul  |   13  |  22/05/2006  
---------+-------+--------------
```

Again, the `width` list will help you in this. Note that, in the horizontal line, the amount of `+` will always be once smaller than the number of rows, and the number of `-` will always be the size of each column, defined by the list `width`.